# How to properly restart a node.js internal process of a .JS script without any plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, restart

What is the most optimal way to restart a js script on interval inside main.js without an extra plugin?
Example contains a generic approach.

**inside main.js**

```
let action1 = require("./actions/action1.js"); 

setInterval(function() { 
try{
let restart = action1 .refresh();
} catch (error) {console.log("Fatal error: ",error,"\r");}

}, 1800000);
```

**action1.js**

```
// lets say contains a scenario of an increment value stored in an array. 
// Refresh() method clear this array on time interval fired by main.js
```

Can node.js handle the situation when a script is running and suddenly main.js calls the same script again? It terminates the script and runs it again? or keeps the old script running and starts the new as new thread?

thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how node.js runs. It may be worth reading through articles on the node.js execution cycle such as [this one](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

Comment: @JohnRC thanks for your pin point on execution cycle. However i'm not aware if restarting a process with Crone job or Interval timer will terminate its previous state to prevent memory issues like overflow. Maybe if you can provide an example will be helpful enough.

Comment: When you use `setInterval()` in node.js, the main.js script (which i presume is the script that was started using node), does not exit. A timer is set up in the Node process to repeatedly call the anon function that calls `action1.refresh()` function at the appropriate interval. So there is one copy of Node running, and it will continue running until it is stopped. If you run the node main.js script again, without terminating the first one, then there will be two executing instnances of the Node running, both of which are calling their own copies of the  'action1.refresh()' function.